# Comparing python tuples with different sizes

Tags: python

Trying to find min value of this tuple, that has different sizes

```
`min(
(10.0, ((-9990, 0), (-9980, 0))), 
(10.0, (-9960, 0), (-9950, 0))
)`
```

I am doing this by using the built-in min function. However, I get this error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'.` I understand it may have something to do with the different sizes of tuples being compared, but it works in the following tuple:

```
`min(
(3426.842861877387, ((8590, 4206), (8666, 7632))), 
(182.7840255602223, (8675, -5692), (8712, -5513))
)`
```

Any ideas what I can do instead, the formatting seems to be the same in both of these examples.

Comment: that is a bit interesting, it seems to take the first value, btw if You change one of the `10.0` values to a different one it will work

Comment: what do you expect to obtain? when is a tuple minor than the other?
eg what would be the output you expect from `min( (2, ((10, 10), (100, 100))), (0, ((20, 0), (5, 3000))) )`
`min` should return one of the two tuples? or a single value? Comparing tuples as objects doesn't make sense, so what do you expect exactly?

Answer (score 2):

This due to how tuples are compared in python. There are pair-wise comparisons, from left to right as long as needed. Consider following examples:

```
(2020, 4) < (2021, "April")  # does work, True
(2021, 3) < (2021, "April")  # TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

In first case 2020 is lesser than 2021, so whole expression is deemed `True` without caring for next elements (c.f. comparing base-2 number for example you can see `0b011` is smaller than `0b100` after checking just first digits of each), in second case comparison of first elements is not enough, so second elements are compared, thus causing attempt of comparing integer to string which cause `TypeError`. If you want to know more read [Comparing Sequences and Other Types in python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

Answer (score 0):

To dig in to the formatting & managing it you can utilize example:

```
a=((10.0, ((-9990, 0), (-9980, 0))),(11.0, ((-9991, 0), (-9982, 0))))

print(min(a))
print(max(a))

print("Minimum of a[0][1] is ",min(a[0][1]))
```